# How to create a executable windows using pyinstaller on linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, kivy, pyinstaller, executable

I've created a new file named: setup.py, follow a tutorial on internet. But I've problem to compile when I call "pyinstaller --onefile -w system/setup.py

bellow is my setup.py, not working

```
import os.path
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages, find_packages
import sysconfig
print('TESTE',sysconfig.__file__)

import system.view.manage
HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
setup(
    name="Docvic",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="Desenvolvido para efetuar um processo de automatização dos documentos",
    long_description="Diversos processos, que irão facilitar todo os procedimentos dos documentos",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="copyvic.com.br",
    author="Douglas Mendes",
    author_email="douglas@copyvic.com.br",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "Documentos mais faceis",
        "Envios para contabilidades",
        "Copyvic - Outsourcing de Impressao"
    ],
    packages=find_namespace_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "altgraph",
        "app-version",
        "argcomplete",
        "asn1crypto",
        "bcrypt",
        "beautifulsoup4",
        "certifi",
        "cffi",
        "chardet",
        "configparser",
        "crypto",
        "cryptography",
        "dbus-python",
        "decorator",
        "docutils",
        "docx2txt",
        "EbookLib",
        "evento",
        "idna",
        "image",
        "JSONFormatBear",
        "jsonpickl",
        "jsonviewer",
        "Kivy",
        "Kivy-Garden",
        "kivy-garden.graph",
        "lxml",
        "Naked",
        "notify",
        "notify2",
        "paramiko",
        "pathlib2",
        "pdfminer.six",
        "pexpect",
        "Pillow",
        "pkg-resources",
        "plyer",
        "pocketsphinx",
        "ptyprocess",
        "PyAutoGUI",
        "pycairo",
        "pycparser",
        "pycrypto",
        "pycryptodome",
        "pydbus",
        "pyftpdlib",
        "pygame",
        "PyGetWindow",
        "Pygments",
        "PyInstaller",
        "PyMsgBox",
        "PyNaCl",
        "pynotify",
        "PyPDF4",
        "PyRect",
        "PyScreeze",
        "pysftp",
        "pytesseract",
        "python-pptx",
        "python3-xlib",
        "PyTweening",
        "pytz",
        "PyYAML",
        "qrcode",
        "requests",
        "sh",
        "shellescape",
        "short-url",
        "six",
        "sortedcontainers",
        "SpeechRecognition",
        "sqlparse",
        "textract",
        "urllib3",
        "validate-email",
        "xlrd",
        "XlsxWriter",
    ],
    #entry_points={"console_scripts":["entry=module.manage"]}  
)
```

My tree:

```
.
├── build
│   └── setup
├── controller
│   ├── AbstractItem.py
│   ├── analiser.py
│   ├── contabil
│   │   ├── DOC_2408201902.json
│   │   ├── DOC_2408201902.png
│   │   ├── DOC_2408201903.json
│   │   └── DOC_2408201903.pdf
│   ├── controller_documento.py
│   ├── folder.py
│   ├── img
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── PROCESS
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── AbstractItem.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── analiser.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── controller_documento.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── ftp_functions.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── qrcodefix.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── sftp_handler.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── sftp_handler.py
├── dist
│   └── teste
├── __init__.py
├── model
│   ├── configsIni.py
│   ├── documento.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── model.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── configsIni.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── documento.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── model.cpython-36.pyc
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── screen.spec
├── setup.py
├── setup.spec
├── teste.spec
├── utils
│   ├── autogui.py
│   ├── ftp_functions.py
│   ├── ftp_handler.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── timerFunctions.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── qrcodefix.py
│   ├── timerFunctions.py
│   └── utils.py
└── view
    ├── files
    ├── icons
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manage
    │   ├── acessJson.py
    │   ├── config32.png
    │   ├── config.png
    │   ├── config.svg
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── manage.ini
    │   ├── manage.kv
    │   ├── manage.py (The file that call all process in my application)
    │   ├── newfile
    │   ├── out.json
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── settingsjson.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── settingsjson.py
    │   └── teste.py
    └── __pycache__
        └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

Comment: Thanks to edit Bill P

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), PyInstaller is tested against Windows, Mac OS X, and GNU/Linux. However, it is not a cross-compiler: to make a Windows app you run PyInstaller in Windows.